# Adding streaming video in web site?

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming

I need to add / include video streaming in a web page of my website. **How can I include video streaming in my web page?**

Can anyone help with sample or examples or with tutorial links?

Comment: Probably belongs on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing much about your requirements, I'd suggest using a free service like http://ustream.tv or http://justin.tv - you can stream videos, your desktop, a camera, etc. They will provide you with a block of HTML that you can paste wherever you like.

Comment: I want to add streaming video like live TV in my blog contetnt. Is  it possible to add live TV into blog content?

Comment: Yes, see the two websites I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Check our Darwin Streaming Server. Open source. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Streaming_Server